# Fixing "An error has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again."

Tags: terminal, centos, gnome-3

I was playing around with the System Settings, and I foolishly increased the Zoom to 10.0 (normal being 1.0), after which the system crashed with an error saying:

> A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again.

How can I use the terminal to change the zoom settings back to normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration settings can be changed using [dconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf). The following command would reset the *magnifier* settings:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/a11y/magnifier/
```

This put all the magnifier settings back to default, and the magnification factor was back to `2.0`.

In general, all the dconf settings can be found by running `dconf dump /`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this steps for fix that error on CentOs 7:
Open terminal: Ctrl+Alt+F2 (or F3)

```
sudo yum history package-list gjs
sudo yum history package-list gnome-shell
sudo yum update --skip-broken
```

After a long wait for the installation to complete , Update complete , Clean up complete. And then restart.

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Then i was able to log in.

Source: https://cdmana.com/2020/12/202012072255252943.html